Connecting to Snowflake using TablePlus
I am using the free version of TablePlus for Windows, but I am unable to connect to Snowflake. I have successfully connected using other tools like DBeaver. Are there any specific points or precautions I should be aware of when connecting with TablePlus?
Error: Snowflake Internal Error: Unable to connect. One or more errors occurred. SqlState: 08006, VendorCode: 270001, QueryId: When I tested the connection, it took a while, and the above error message was displayed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
